# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error - create an account

Tags: laravel

Im using laravel auth. In the register page the user needs to fill in the name, surname, email and password to create an account. Later  the user can edit his profile account and insert more info like address, city, zipcode, etc, but to create account its just necessary name, surname, email and password.

Im structuring this above logic with the code below using the laravel auth, but Im getting an error after filling the form and click in "Create Account":

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'facebook_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (...)

Do you know what is the error in the code below?

**Routes:**

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

**User table migration:**

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('facebook_id')->unique();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->dateTime('dateRegister');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->string('zipCode');
            $table->string('city');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
   }
```

**User model:**

```
   class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'facebook_id', ''
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];
   }
```

**RegisterController:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),

        ]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If during registration you're passing Facebook ID, add it:

```
return User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    'facebook_id' => $data['facebook_id']
]);
```

If not, make this column nullable:

```
$table->string('facebook_id')->unique()->nullable();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `migration` and allow `facebook_id` to be null, otherwise provide `facebook_id` when `inserting`:

```
$table->string('facebook_id')->unique()->nullable();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need either pass the field to `create()` method with value or make it `nullable` in migration

```
$table->string('facebook_id')->unique()->nullable();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not providing the `facebook_id` to `create` method then make it **nullable** in migration file

```
$table->string('facebook_id')->unique()->nullable();
```